# iOS Gesture Recognizer About Protractor: A Fast and Accurate Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

Recently,I have been doing a project about gesture recognizer.I found two kinds of algorithm named: Protractor: A Fast and Accurate Gesture Recognizer and $1 gesture recognizer.

And the paper address: https://www.lri.fr/~anab/teaching/M2R-2011/5-gestures/protractor-chi2010.pdf

I can understand how does it work.However,I don't understand the pseudo code.I will pose it later.If anyone can help me? My math isn't so good.

```
OPTIMAL-COSINE-DISTANCE (vector, vector$)

1 a = 0

2 b = 0

3 for i from 1 to |vector| Step 2 do

4 a ← a + vectori × vector$i+ vectori+1 × vector$i+1

5 b ← b + vectori × vector$i+1 – vectori+1 × vector$i

6 angle ← ATAN (b/a)

7 return ACOS (a × COS (angle) + b × SIN (angle))
```

My question is :

Why ACOS (a × COS (angle) + b × SIN (angle)) ? It returns what ? Thank you~